# I am not an aol user yet I am receiving emails to various addresses with my name and different letters numbers to my gmail account

Tags: email, gmail

I have all my email accounts with gmail and yet I am receiving emails from US companies to an aol email account with various mike**@aol.com addresses 1) why are these not going into my junk mail 2) why am I receiving these and keep blocking them when they are not my email address 3) what can I do about it I have tried sending an email of complaint to aol but they do not see the “Value” in the email addresses I’m entering
Please help

Comment: The technical "why" is easily answered: that's how Bcc works. The indicated recipient address and the actual delivery destination need not match.

Comment: Give an example of the headers of one such email.